# Issue with wisdom generator

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display random wisdom on a web page but I cannot figure out why the code below does not work.

Thank you

My javascript external file is:

```
function random(low, high) { 
return Math.floor(Math.random()*(high-low+1)) + low;}

function randomarr() {
var arr = new Array("...1", "...2", "...3");
return arr[random(0, arr.length-1)];}

function display(){
var k = randomarr();
alert(k);}
```

and my html file

In the head section I've got:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
src="java.js"
</script>
```

And in the body section I've got:

```
<p>
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.write(display());
</script>
</p>
```

Comment: i know this isn't exactly related to your question, but JavaScript actually isn't related to Java, so having a `java.js` file is an interesting naming choice that I wouldn't reccomend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for including the script in the `<head>` is wrong. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>
```